# How do you test router match params with jest and enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

Say I have the following component which I grabbed from https://www.codeday.top/2017/11/08/56644.html. Here I am using match.params to access the id. How would I write a unit test for this component tests the presence of the h2 element using Jest+Enzyme+Typescript+React.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Link, match } from 'react-router-dom';

// define React components for multiple pages
class Home extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>HOME</div>
        <div><Link to='/details/id123'>Goto Details</Link></div>
      </div>);
  }
}

interface DetailParams {
  id: string;
}

interface DetailsProps {
  required: string;
  match?: match<DetailParams>;
}

class Details extends React.Component<DetailsProps, any> {
  render() {
    const match = this.props.match;
    if (match) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Details for {match.params.id}</h2>
          <Link to='/'>Goto Home</Link>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <div>Error Will Robinson</div>
          <Link to='/'>Goto Home</Link>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/details/:id" component={(props) => <Details required="some string" {...props} />} />
    </div>
  </Router>

  , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [containsMatchingElement](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/containsMatchingElement.md)

```
const wrapper = shallow(
  <Details
    required={true}
    match={{params: {id: 1}, isExact: true, path: "", url: ""}}
  />
);
expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<h2>Details for 1</h2>)).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: can you use path or url to set location or do you just use     **window.location = 'http://localhost:3000/foo'**

Comment: I think you just have to supply `match` prop. Converting from real url to `match` prop is the work of routing library so we don't need to test it.

Comment: @paibamboo Is there any method to create a match object instead of hard-coding it? Like`createBrowserHistory()`

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, this doc - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/match.md - just tells us how to use it, not how to create it.

Answer (score 4):

## Wrap All Tests In Context

Router exists in context, so you can wrap your tests in context and supply match params to it to test how your component picks them up.

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { shape } from 'prop-types';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

// Instantiate router context
const router = route => ({
  history: new BrowserRouter().history,
  route,
});

const createContext = route => ({
  context: { ...router(route) },
  childContextTypes: { router: shape({}) },
});

export function mountWrap(node, route) {
  return mount(node, createContext(route));
}
```

Example describe:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TableC } from '../../src/tablec';
import { mountWrap, shallowWrap } from '../testhelp/contextWrap';
import { expectedProps } from './mockdata'

describe('Table', () => {
  let props;
  let component;
  let route = {
    location: {},
    match: {[MATCH OBJ HERE]}
  }

  const wrappedMount = () => mountWrap(<TableC {...props} />, route);

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      query: {
        data: tableData,
        refetch: jest.fn(),
      },
    };
    if (component) component.unmount();
  });

  test('should call a DeepTable with correct props', () => {
    let route = {
      location: {},
      match: {[UPDATE MATCH OBJ HERE BEFORE TEST]}
    }
    const wrapper = wrappedMount();
    expect(wrapper.find('DeepTable').props()).toEqual(expectedProps);
  });

});
```

This also allows you to optionally add other things to context, and allows the top level object in the wrapper to be your component (as opposed to wrapping with BrowserRouter or StaticRouter)

Comment: Do you have a typescript friendly version of that code for contextWrap.ts

Comment: For ES7, use a spread operator on `router(route)`, i. e. `...router(route)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
const wrapper = mount(
  <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/1234']}>
    <Route exact path="/:id/" component={Details} />
  </MemoryRouter>
);
```

Comment: Please consider adding a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help readers to better understand your solution.